# React JS keyDown Listener glitching

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, keylistener

In my code I have:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  });
```

This creates an event listener to listen to my keyboard. Then on my handleKeyDown I have:

```
const [keys, setKeys] = useState([]);

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    console.log(event.key);
    if (event.repeat) {
      return;
    }

    const key = event.key;
    if (!keys.includes(key)) {
      let updatedPressedKeys = [...keys];
      updatedPressedKeys.push(key);
      setKeys(updatedPressedKeys);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };
```

Basically, I have a `keys` array variable. And I want to add every unique key pressed onto the keys variable. So I first check if the user is holding down the key. Then I check if the current key pressed is in `keys`, if not I add it into keys. However when I run my code, the first time I press a key the handleKeyDown method is called once. Then when i let go and press my second key, the method gets called twice. Then it gets called 4 times, then 8. Eventually it takes a long time and gets laggy. I'm not sure why the method gets called more time each time. Please let me know whats wrong. Refer to the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your component renders you are adding a new event listener in the `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
});
```

You should add a dependency array and clean up function. The empty dependency array will act as a "componentDidMount" effect to add the listener only once, and the cleanup function acts as a "componentWillUnmount" function to clean up/remove the listener.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  };
}, []);
```

You may also want to convert the listener callback to use a functional state update so you won't have a stale state enclosure.

```
const [keys, setKeys] = useState([]);

const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
  const { key } = event;

  console.log(key);

  if (event.repeat) {
    return;
  }

  setKeys(keys => {
    if (!keys.includes(key)) {
      return [...keys, key];
    }
    return keys;
  });
};
```